# How can I keep bookmarks synchronised between Qt and GTK applications?

Tags: gtk, qt, filemanager, bookmarks

Does anyone know a solution to keeping the same bookmarks (red rectangle in the screenshots) between Qt-based and GTK-based applications?

### Qt-based applications:

[image]

### GTK-based applications:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As of 23 June 2023, the top Google result is a tool called `bookmarksync`, at https://github.com/jlu5/bookmarksync. Although it doesn't appear to be in active development, I was able to successfully compile and use it through the AUR package on Manjaro Linux.

[image]